# Rewrite all 'File' (title) fields in Wordpress Media Library to match Post Title

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-3.5

I recently migrated and upgraded my Wordpress site.

The new installation picked up all the images, but in the media library, the images 'File' fields are all blank, i.e. showing "(no title)".

This causes me a problem when I want to search for images. I have around 400 posts, and one image per post, so I would like match each image name with its associated post name.

I'm hoping to run a script once that will achieve this, or potentially use some code in my functions file.

Note 1: I have tried a couple of plugins called 'Rename media' and 'Rename media files' etc. but they didn't work. Their focus was on renaming the actual image files.

Note 2: I have since used a plugin to auto-generate thumbnails for each image -- I don't think that should cause any issues for what I want to achieve however.

UPDATE: While I haven't found the solution for populating the title fields, I have found a workaround to the search issue. I installed a plugin called 'Media Search' which includes the attached page or post in the default media library search:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-search/

However, the plugin version 1.2 was not working with Wordpress 3.5, but via the plugin support page I found that another person had created a working modification, that added additional capabilities (searches image alt, caption and description):
http://pastebin.com/f6V5HvfT

Comment: I should add that I have tried a couple of plugins called 'Rename media' and 'Rename media files' etc. but they didn't work.  Their focus was on renaming the actual image files.

Comment: Add your comment in your question ("edit" button), so everyone can see it.

Comment: Would be better to try to correct what went wrong in the first place, the migration. Did the site URL changed? If so, how did you modify it? I assume the previous install had the titles correctly set, right?

Comment: No, I didn't have titles set in the previous install, but I also upgraded WP. Titles are a feature of the Media Library that weren't available in my previous install. So I'm looking to populate titles, so that I can avail of the new search capability of Media Library.